# Script working only when current tab is at a certain website

Tags: autohotkey

How would I be able to have a script run only if I'm visiting a certain webpage? For instance, to scan for a certain string in the address bar and if it finds it to work.

Comment: Which browser do you prefer? IE does have direct COM support, Chrome and FF require another approach. e.g. in Chrome you could retrieve the current URL through: "ControlGetText, CurrentURL, Chrome_OmniboxView1, Chrome"

Answer (score 1):

Web browsers typically update their window titles to include the name of the current site being shown. Autohotkey has the ability to run a function when a window appears with certain text in its title (see [`IfWinActive`](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfWinActive.htm) and [`WaitWinActive`](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWaitActive.htm)).